# MySQL Transaction Question - Order of operation in calling

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

Update: MySQL Version 8.0.34

My understanding is MySQL is purely synchronous in operation and when a connection calls a stored procedure, the database doesn't "return" from that call (regardless of how deep it goes - A>B>C>D) until it's complete, and the database won't execute any other SP (with that connection) until it completes.

What I'm confused about is when I snapshot `information_schema.INNODB_TRX` at the beginning of a SP, it will show a previous SP call still "running". This makes no sense to me. Note I'm talking about the same connection (not multiple connections - so just querying the same session).

How could `information_schema.INNODB_TRX` have a running transaction from a previous call when a new SP is being called? It it just table delay, or is something else going on I'm unaware of?

Note the running transaction is nearly always a CALL to a stored procedure (a different one).

UPDATE for clarity

1. 1st ROOT Stored Procedure A is called. Does B, C, D, etc.
2. 2nd ROOT Stored Procedure E is called. Transaction log shows CALL
   transaction RUNNING from Procedure A call.

Comment: Do you mean you called a second procedure, still in the context of a single transaction started earlier, and you're wondering why this is? It's true you can call many procedures or run many other SQL queries in one transaction. Is this a surprise?

Comment: I tried testing, but I can't reproduce what you describe. Can you confirm what `SELECT VERSION();` says on your MySQL instance? I am using 8.2.0.

Comment: Transactions lock tables and rows, they don't lock at the procedure level.

Comment: Hey @BillKarwin I updated things above. I'm confused because my understanding is MySQL must exist the "root" SP call and all transactions associated with it before allowing another SP to be executed - yes? Or no...?

Comment: Yes, each session is single-threaded. There are no asynchronous queries or calls for a given session. Even triggers run synchronously.

Comment: @BillKarwin then how is a "root" call (that can only be called externally) showing a transaction for the session from a previous root call? That's why I'm confused. Is it possible the transaction is a "delayed list" from the previous SP call and it's already completed?

Comment: It's possible the INNODB_TRX table is reporting an outdated state. But I can't reproduce the issue from the information you have described, so I can't do any testing to confirm that.